Selenide 7.6.0 Video recorder not working / wrong implementation
I finally got around to upgrading the Selenide version from a month ago, and I got interested in the new feature regarding test recording.
I wanted to implement it in one of my codes:
Selenide-JUnit5-Cucumber
Selenide-TestNG-Cucumber
Unfortunately, both attempts ended with a failure. Following the documentation, it seems the topic is simple, but I can't figure out what exactly needs to be done to make it work in the simplest possible form.
CucumberRunner
@EnableVideo
    @ExtendWith(VideoRecorderExtension.class)
    public class RunCucumberTests
    {
    
    }

StepDefinition
@ExtendWith(VideoRecorderExtension.class)
@EnableVideo
public class StarterStep
{
    @BeforeAll 
    static void setUp() {
        // Konfiguracja ścieżki do nagrań

        System.setProperty("selenide.video.directory", "target/videos"); 
        System.setProperty("selenide.video.enabled", "true"); 

    }
    @Video
    @Given("Start testing")
    public void openBrowser(){
        open("https://www.saucedemo.com/");
    }

Selenide Configuration.class i don't see there any methods which can handle video records. like video enable etc.
package com.codeborne.selenide;

import org.jspecify.annotations.Nullable;
import org.openqa.selenium.MutableCapabilities;

public class Configuration {
    private static final SelenideConfig defaults = new SelenideConfig();
    public static String baseUrl;
    public static long timeout;
    public static long pollingInterval;
    /** @deprecated */
    @Deprecated
    public static boolean holdBrowserOpen;
    public static boolean reopenBrowserOnFail;
    public static String browser;
    public static @Nullable String browserVersion;
    public static @Nullable String remote;
    public static @Nullable String browserSize;
    public static @Nullable String browserPosition;
    public static MutableCapabilities browserCapabilities;
    public static String pageLoadStrategy;
    public static long pageLoadTimeout;
    public static boolean clickViaJs;
    public static boolean screenshots;
    public static boolean savePageSource;
    public static String reportsFolder;
    public static String downloadsFolder;
    public static @Nullable String reportsUrl;
    public static boolean fastSetValue;
    public static TextCheck textCheck;
    public static SelectorMode selectorMode;
    public static AssertionMode assertionMode;
    public static FileDownloadMode fileDownload;
    public static boolean proxyEnabled;
    public static @Nullable String proxyHost;
    public static int proxyPort;
    public static boolean webdriverLogsEnabled;
    public static boolean headless;
    public static @Nullable String browserBinary;
    public static long remoteReadTimeout;
    public static long remoteConnectionTimeout;

    public Configuration() {
    }

    public static SelenideConfig config() {
        return (new SelenideConfig()).baseUrl(baseUrl).timeout(timeout).pollingInterval(pollingInterval).holdBrowserOpen(holdBrowserOpen).reopenBrowserOnFail(reopenBrowserOnFail).browser(browser).browserVersion(browserVersion).remote(remote).browserSize(browserSize).browserPosition(browserPosition).browserCapabilities(browserCapabilities).pageLoadStrategy(pageLoadStrategy).pageLoadTimeout(pageLoadTimeout).clickViaJs(clickViaJs).screenshots(screenshots).savePageSource(savePageSource).reportsFolder(reportsFolder).downloadsFolder(downloadsFolder).reportsUrl(reportsUrl).fastSetValue(fastSetValue).textCheck(textCheck).selectorMode(selectorMode).assertionMode(assertionMode).fileDownload(fileDownload).proxyEnabled(proxyEnabled).proxyHost(proxyHost).proxyPort(proxyPort).webdriverLogsEnabled(webdriverLogsEnabled).headless(headless).browserBinary(browserBinary).remoteReadTimeout(remoteReadTimeout).remoteConnectionTimeout(remoteConnectionTimeout);
    }

    static {
        baseUrl = defaults.baseUrl();
        timeout = defaults.timeout();
        pollingInterval = defaults.pollingInterval();
        holdBrowserOpen = defaults.holdBrowserOpen();
        reopenBrowserOnFail = defaults.reopenBrowserOnFail();
        browser = defaults.browser();
        browserVersion = defaults.browserVersion();
        remote = defaults.remote();
        browserSize = defaults.browserSize();
        browserPosition = defaults.browserPosition();
        browserCapabilities = defaults.browserCapabilities();
        pageLoadStrategy = defaults.pageLoadStrategy();
        pageLoadTimeout = defaults.pageLoadTimeout();
        clickViaJs = defaults.clickViaJs();
        screenshots = defaults.screenshots();
        savePageSource = defaults.savePageSource();
        reportsFolder = defaults.reportsFolder();
        downloadsFolder = defaults.downloadsFolder();
        reportsUrl = defaults.reportsUrl();
        fastSetValue = defaults.fastSetValue();
        textCheck = defaults.textCheck();
        selectorMode = defaults.selectorMode();
        assertionMode = defaults.assertionMode();
        fileDownload = defaults.fileDownload();
        proxyEnabled = defaults.proxyEnabled();
        proxyHost = defaults.proxyHost();
        proxyPort = defaults.proxyPort();
        webdriverLogsEnabled = defaults.webdriverLogsEnabled();
        headless = defaults.headless();
        browserBinary = defaults.browserBinary();
        remoteReadTimeout = defaults.remoteReadTimeout();
        remoteConnectionTimeout = defaults.remoteConnectionTimeout();
    }
}


While your are using JUnit 5 to run Cucumber that does not mean you can use extensions.
https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#overview-what-is-junit-5

Unlike previous versions of JUnit, JUnit 5 is composed of several different modules from three different sub-projects.
JUnit 5 = JUnit Platform + JUnit Jupiter + JUnit Vintage

Here JUnit Jupiter, JUnit Vintage and Cucumber are test engines on the JUnit Platform. And extensions are a Jupiter concept that can only be used with JUnit Jupiter.
Fortunately the video recorder extensions is relatively simple. If you look at the source
you can probably use the VideoRecorder with Cucumber using the @BeforeAll, @AfterAll, @Before and @After hooks.

To be honest, it seemed really simple to me at first. A simple annotation, a few variables to manage it, and everything should work. However, I haven't yet found any information indicating that someone has actually used it successfully, and I'm curious if anyone has really made use of it.
I tagged both the test steps (step definitions) and hooks, added the Video annotation to both the Before hooks and test steps. I set the variables that should somehow manage this, but unfortunately, there’s still no sign of anything happening. I've added more information in 2nd answer

The annotation will not work with Cucumber. Period. The annotation is for an extension, extensions are for JUnit Jupiter only. Jupiter is part of JUnit 5, but not all of JUnit 5. Cucumber does not (and can not) understand those annotations.  Instead you'll have to program the function the extension provides yourself, using Cucumbers @BeforeAll, @AfterAll, @Before and @After hooks.

To program that functionality, you can look at the source of the extension and see what it does. Using the VideoRecorder doesn't look too complicated.

I finally understood that u wanted to tell me. So the finally solution is to write own function to handle this.
